# Charles, empty request body with non-empty response body

Tags: ios, charles-proxy

I used Charles to record a session and when I check one of the sessions, I found that there is no request body but I can see a response body, I am confused about this as how am I seeing a response without sending a request?

[image]

[image]

Also, I noticed that I can choose to see the request and response body on my phone's Charles, but on my desktop Charles, I can only see the tab called Content, I tried clicking on the request and response in the under the View tab, nothing happened as well.  Does anyone know why?
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused about this as how am I seeing a response without sending a request?

A request consists of a few things:

- Always: an HTTP method (GET, POST, or similar)
- Always: a path (/document/123)
- Optional: any number of HTTP headers (my-header: abc)
- Optional: a request body

A response consists of:

- Always: an HTTP status (404)
- Always (in HTTP/1): an HTTP status message (Not Found)
- Optional: any number of HTTP headers (my-header: abc)
- Optional: a response body

In your case, you are sending a request, it's just that your request only contains a method, URL and headers, but no body. **That's totally normal** and this is very common for most HTTP requests.

The request and response body are totally independent: it's fine for neither to have a body, or for just one (either one) to have a body, or for both to have a body.

As an example, a GET request to https://google.com/search from a browser will include a method (GET) and a path (/search) and a selection of headers from the browser (such as a user-agent), but won't include any body, and the response will have a status (200) and message (OK), headers about the response data (e.g. content-length: ...) and the body will be the HTML for the google search page.

Comment: Hey Tim!  Thanks for the help!  That was very clear! I have a quick question related to the path in HTTP method.  If I recorded the process of login into the app, and Charles returned this “POST /profiles/Candidates/Login?languageId=1 HTTP/1.1” under my Request tab, does that mean I should add the path to my host if I want to send a login request to the host? Like if my host is "prod-t2-api.adia.com", I should send the request to " http://prod-t2-api.adia.com/profiles/Candidates/Login?languageId=1 HTTP/1.1"?

Comment: Yes - if the path is relative (if it starts with a slash, not with http://...) then to get the full URL you should put the hostname in front.

Comment: For some reason, I sent my request to 'http://prod-t2-api.adia.com/profiles/Candidates/Login?languageId=1' , I keep getting this error "{'statusCode': 404, 'message': 'Resource not found'}", I am kinda lost on here as I don't find myself doing anything wrong.  (I actually added a "http://" in front of the URL but it is not showing for some reason.)